# Try Catch in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql, sql-server, try-catch, sql-server-2000

Is it possible using Try-Catch in `SQL Server 2000`?

Comment: No. Only in 2005 and 2008, 2008 R2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

This was only from Sql Server 2005

Check [TRY...CATCH (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976(v=SQL.90).aspx) and check the *Other Versions*

Answer (score 6):

No. `Try Catch` block was introduced in `SQL SERVER 2005`.

Following article shows how you can use `@@ERROR` to check for errors.

[Understanding error handling in SQL Server 2000](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6079583.html)

Answer (score 4):

Instead you can user `@@Error`..

check [this](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6079583.html) article about error handling

Answer (score 1):

`@@ERROR` is a variable updated by the SQL Server database engine after each statement is executed on the server.
    We can see by Print `@@Error`

Answer (score 0):

No Try Catch Was introduced 2005 and later version ,,,you have to use @@Error for handling your exception

Comment: Don't you think it is a little bit late? Like 4 years?