# sql server 2000 try catch

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

There is no try...catch in sql server 2000 like in 2005?
If not what is the equivalent for try...catch in 2000?
If there is, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524566/try-catch-in-sql-server

Answer (score 10):

there is no such thing in 2000...Checking @@error is your option and using XACT_ABORT

Here are two good links for you  http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-II.html and http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html  both written by  Erland Sommarskog